# How to capture child checkbox click event inside parent li?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events

I have the following Vue Code that shows the structure that we're using:

```
<template>
  <li class="mm-product-item" v-on:click="edit(item)">
    <p class="mm-product-info input-field">
      <input type="checkbox"
              class="filled-in"
              :id="'checkbox-' + item.id"
              :checked="item.addNextOrder"
              v-on:click.capture.stop="toggleNextOrder($event, item.id)" />
      <label :for="'checkbox-' + item.id"></label>
      <span class="mm-product-name" click="edit(item)">{{ item.name }}</span>
      <span class="mm-product-quantity">{{ item.quantity }}</span>
      <span class="mm-product-unit">{{ item.selectedUnit }}</span>
    </p>

    <button href="#remove-product" @click.prevent.stop="destroy(item.id)" class="mm-product-remove" title="remover produto">&times;</button>
  </li>
</template>
```

So there's a `checkbox` nested inside a `p` nested inside an `li`.

The `li`, as the parent, has a wider, larger area that should trigger the `edit(item)` method. This works just fine.

The `checkbox`, although smaller, should also capture the click event and trigger the `toggleNextOrder` method.

If no event is specified in the `li`, the `checkbox` event handling works just fine.

But if the `li` event exists (as in the snippet above), the `checkbox` event won't even happen, but it should, according to [Vue's documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers).

I was able to make a similar situation work just fine [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaysoifer/x3a46v8x/) but, for some reason, in this production environment it is not working.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you replicate the error with the code causing the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: If you remove the inner onClick in your JSFiddle, it still works. So it seems your inner onClick is doing nothing. Perhaps you could do a similar thing for your production code where you send `$event` as a parameter in the `li` onClick and if your `$event` is on the checkbox, then you call `toggleNextOrder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening with the help of Chrome Dev Tools.

There's a label right next to the checkbox, associated to it:

```
<input type="checkbox" (...) />
<label :for="'checkbox-' + item.id" (...) ></label>
```

#### Inspecting the `<input type=checkbox>` using Google Chrome's Dev Tools, it seems like the checkbox "has no area":

[image: Checkbox Screenshot]

•••

#### **While inspecting the `<label>` right next to it, shows me it actually "wraps and surrounds" the checkbox:**

•••

[image: Label Screenshot]

#### So I added the `@click.capture.stop.prevent="toggleNextOrder(item.id)"` Event Handler to the label, instead of the checkbox and now it works.